# Only one SimpleButton in wx.lib.agw.ribbon causes bad layout

Tags: wxpython, ribbon

The good result:

[image]

The bad result:

[image]

I don't have user experience with the ribbon interface, therefore can't understand what happens:

- Is it a bug?
- Or is it intended behaviour, and I should somehow tune the layout?

The code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ribbon as RB
#import ribbon as RB

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
  def __init__(self, *ls, **kw):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *ls, **kw)
    ribbon = RB.RibbonBar(self, -1)

    page = RB.RibbonPage(ribbon, wx.ID_ANY, "Page")
    panel = RB.RibbonPanel(page, wx.ID_ANY, "Create Project")
    bbar = RB.RibbonButtonBar(panel)
    bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW, wx.ART_OTHER, wx.Size(48, 48))
    bbar.AddSimpleButton(wx.ID_ANY, "New", bmp, '')
    #bbar.AddSimpleButton(wx.ID_ANY, "New2", bmp, '') # uncomment for the good result

    ribbon.Realize()
    s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    s.Add(ribbon, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(s)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
dlg = MyDialog(None, title="Test Ribbon", size=(200,150))
dlg.ShowModal()
dlg.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug. When the text on `RibbonPanel` is longer than its content, it breaks. Try this:

```
panel = RB.RibbonPanel(page, wx.ID_ANY, "Create...")
```

You may be able to add some empty widget next to the button to overcome the issue.

There is a nice set of docs and examples located here:

- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ribbon_module.html#ribbon
- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/RibbonBar.html